# How to update Blazor UI in same callback before calling a ref function?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my component, I have a child component (`FooComponent`) where I pass a parameter to it and also get a ref.

**Parent.razor**

```
<FooComponent @ref="FooComponentRef" FooParameter="@MyValue"/>
    
<button @onclick="Test">@MyValue</button>
    
@code {
    FooComponent FooComponentRef { get; set; }
    
    string MyValue { get; set; }
    
    int count { get; set; }
    
    void Test(){
        MyValue = "SomeValue" + count++;            
        FooComponentRef.FooFunction();
    }
}
```

*I modified the code so it's a simple and testable example*

And I have a function (`Test`) that will update the property that is passed in the parameter (`MyValue` passed to `FooParameter`) and call a function from the ref (`FooFunction` of `FooComponent`).

And inside the `FooComponent`

**FooComponent.razor**

```
<div>
    <div>FooParameter: @FooParameter</div>
    <div>ValueUsedInFooFunction: @ValueUsedInFooFunction</div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string FooParameter { get; set; }

    public string ValueUsedInFooFunction { get; set; }

    public void FooFunction()
    {
        // This function is using FooParameter to make some logic
        ValueUsedInFooFunction = FooParameter;
    }
}
```

*I modified the code so it's a simple and testable example*

It uses the `FooParameter` in the `FooFunction` to do some logic.

The problem is that when I change the `MyValue` and call `FooFunction`, the component didn't update yet, so it uses the "old" value of `FooParameter`, but I need to use the new setted value, which is the correct `MyValue`.

Another thing that makes this hard to solve is that I can't change the `FooFunction` (it's not a function that I created).

I have tried using everything (`StateHasChanged`, `InvokeAsync`) but still no solution.

What I need is my `Test` function to do something like

```
void Test(){
    MyValue = "SomeValue" + count++;   
    
    // Somehow update UI so FooParameter have the correct value of MyValue          
    
    FooComponentRef.FooFunction();    
}
```

Here is the [blazor fiddle to test](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/o4mgwnvv)

In the fiddle, when clicking in the button and calling `Test`function, you will see that the `ValueUsedInFooFunction` is always the "old" value of `FooParameter`, meaning that the `FooFunction` is being executed before the `FooParameter` is being updated.

Comment: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/dhm3gr45

Answer (score 0):

This change will make this work:

```
 void Test(){
    MyValue = "SomeValue" + count++;    
    FooComponentRef.FooParameter = MyValue;
    FooComponentRef.FooFunction();
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to set a component's property this way as it bypasses blazors methods (OnParametersSet for instance). Infact it even generates an analyzer warning `BL0005` (Component parameters should not be set outside of their declared component. Doing so may result in unexpected behavior at runtime.)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the string parameter (MyValue), you will pass an object, a Dto, that has one string property that will contain the value. This is the Dto:

```
   public class FooDto
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is Index:

```
  @page "/"
@using WebApplication2.Models

<FooComponent @ref="FooComponentRef" FooDtoParameter="@_dto" />

<button @onclick="Test">@MyValue</button>

@code {
    FooComponent FooComponentRef { get; set; }

    string MyValue { get; set; }

    int count { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        
    // The Dto class will be passed as a parameter to foo.
    _dto = new FooDto();
    }

    void Test()
    {
        _dto.MyValue = "SomeValue" + count++;

        FooComponentRef.FooFunction();
    }

    
    private FooDto _dto;
}
```

Foo:

```
@using WebApplication2.Models
<div>
    <div>FooParameter: @FooDtoParameter.MyValue</div>
    <div>ValueUsedInFooFunction: @ValueUsedInFooFunction</div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public FooDto FooDtoParameter { get; set; }

    public string ValueUsedInFooFunction { get; set; }

    public void FooFunction()
    {
    // This function is using FooParameter to make some logic
        ValueUsedInFooFunction = FooDtoParameter.MyValue;
    }
}
```

The Child and parent component are using the same Dto object to communicate, when you change the value of the property, the child component has instant access to that information.

I understand there may be better ways to do this, but I am trying to answer the question on this specific case.